# Not null bug in PHP or not?

Tags: php, string, null

I don't know if it is a bug or what but here it is. I  `var_dump` my
 variable `status_id` it says:

```
var_dump($status_id);
string(4) "null"
```

but when I `var_dump` it says:

```
var_dump($status_id != NULL);
bool(true)
```

How can I transform it to null again because I need it to my filter?

Comment: a string with "null" inside is not NULL (it is a string with "null" inside)

Comment: what you have is null in string

Comment: Protip: if you're doing something incredibly basic in one of the world's most popular programming languages and it doesn't do what you expect, its never a bug in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `$status_id` is a string `'null'`, not `null` or `NULL`. Check the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/804200) for a good understanding.

You can compare it with `$status_id == 'null'`

or set it to null with `$status_id = $status_id == 'null' ? null : $status_id;`

Comment: so how can I transform it to null again, I really need it to my filter

Comment: thank you for your answer I change my if to 'null' so that it will not give me hassle in converting it

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$status_id` is not null, it has a string value as "null". Check this out:

```
<?php
$val="null";
var_dump($val);
// Output: string(4) "null"

$val2;
var_dump($val2);
// Output: NULL
```

Comment: so how can I transform it to null again, I need it to my filter

Comment: you can compare it will "null" value `if($val==="null")`

Answer (score -1):

The PHP var_dump() function returns the data type and value:

so you are getting string value "null" not NULL

Answer (score -1):

Just this `var_dump($status_id != NULL);` will trigger an PHP Notice Error
`Notice: Undefined variable: status_id`
Better to use

```
if( !isset($status_id) ) {}
```

Or if it is set, but without value

```
if( !empty($status_id) ) {}
```